# How to declare objects, not create new ones?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know how to create a new variables in python

```
obj = MyClass()
```

But this will actually define a new variable named `obj` other than just declaring a variable of `MyClass`.

In Java we declare it using `MyClass obj;` and define `MyClass obj = new MyClass();`

Can we achieve the same in Python?

Comment: You don't need to declare things before using them

Comment: What would be the *point* of *"declaring a variable"* without an object in Python? They're really just *names*, tags on/"pointers" to objects. You could do e.g. `obj = None`, but there's little point. Read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You declare some variable for compilers  to do check. Python don't need compile. So there is need to do such kind of declare.

Comment: Do you need the uninitialized variable for something specific? What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "declaring an object" in Python. If you want to create a **name** in a scope then you must **bind** it to an object, either existing or new.

```
somename = someobj
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is based on strong, dynamic, duck typing. Therefore, a variable does not have a type and does not need to be pre-defined.

If you'd like to define variables upfront, you may by doing something like:

```
my_string_var = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has no explicit variable declarations. Variables are just created by assigning a value, and they are automatically destroyed when they go out of scope.

Just:

```
obj = SomeObject()
```

When it comes to defining a class:

Old style:

```
class MyClass:
    pass
```

New style:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass
```